# How to access second element in a Sequence in scala

Tags: scala

```
val k = Seq((0,1),(1,2),(2,3),(3,4))
k: Seq[(Int, Int)] = List((0,1), (1,2), (2,3), (3,4))
```

If I have above statement and I need to do addition for even places and subtraction for odd places how can I access them? to be clear

- (0,1) has to become (0,(1+2))
- (1,2) has to become (1,(1-2))
- (2,3) has to become (2,(3+4))
- (3,4) has to become (3,(3-4)

Comment: Your question is not clear. Where are the "1" and "2" coming from in the addition. Are they coming from the next element in the sequence? Can you give a formula in addition to the example?

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean something like this?

```
val transformed = k.grouped(2).flatMap{
  case Seq((i, x), (j, y)) => Seq((i, x + y), (j, x - y))
}

transformed.toList
// List[(Int, Int)] = List((0,3), (1,-1), (2,7), (3,-1))
```